# Why use regular expression [*?[] for magic_check ?

Tags: python, regex, shell, glob

A regular expression in Python's *glob* module, approx line 92,

```
magic_check = re.compile('[*?[]')
```

I assume this is to check if a pattern has characters `*` and `?` inside, which are frequently used in many shell context. But what about `[`? What is the meaning of `[` in bash or other commonly used shells? Or `[` has special function in the regular expression?

Comment: It really irritates me to see unescaped open brackets in non-java classes. Visually its appaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In filename glob, `[a-c]` matches a character between `a` and `c` : `a`, `b`, `c`.

Example:

```
$ touch a
$ touch b
$ touch c
$ touch d
$ ls [a-c]
a  b  c
```

Answer (score 2):

[ and [[ are used to create conditional expression in bash, which are commonly used in if and while statements. If you type `help [` in bash it help explain how they work.

**EDIT**
I just realized this is in the context of globbing. In this case, the appropriate meaning is that in bash you can use character classes in globs, in a similar way to character classes in regular expressions. Ex: `file_[0-9].txt` would match file_0.txt, file_1.txt, etc.

Comment: I know that `[` is equivalent to `test` in bash. But does that used in a pattern for file name globbing? e.g. `find -name '<some_chars>[<other_chars>'`